# Coming up with a system of linear equations to determine points of intersection between a plane and two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

This was one of the questions on my midterm that I was unable to answer and I still don't know how this is done. The question gives us a plane in vector form and 2 lines also in vector form. Our task was to come up with a system of linear equations to determine whether or not the intersection of these three sets is non-empty.

The answer is in the image, I just want to know how this was done. I would be very grateful for an explanation.

Set A refers to a plane while Sets B and C are lines.

[Question and answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGIwE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the equation for plane A mark parameters t and s as $ x_1 $ and $ x_2 $.
In the equation for line B mark parameter t as $ x_3 $.
In the equation for line C mark parameter t as $ x_4 $.

Each set of three equations corresponds to one of the following

A - B = 0

B - C = 0

A - C = 0.